# Issue with next.js/typescript/webpack: "Unhandled Rejection (ReferenceError): XYZ is not defined"

Tags: typescript, webpack, next.js

Please find below three files of a demo next.js/TypeScript project.
Please be aware that `SomeType.ts`has a TS type as default export and `some-stuff.ts` has a TS type and a JS object as exports.
I think this should work, but instead I get the following error message - does anyone know what could be the problem?

[image: error message]

---

pages/SomeType.ts:

```js
  type SomeType = { a: number, b: number }

  export default SomeType
```

---

pages/some-stuff.ts:

```js
  import SomeType from './SomeType'

  const someValue: SomeType = { a: 11, b: 22 }

  export {
    someValue,

    // If we would not export SomeType
    // the demo would work fine - very strange...
    SomeType
  }
```

---

pages/index.ts

```js
  import { someValue } from './some-stuff'

  export default () => JSON.stringify(someValue)
```

Comment: I don't know much about typescript but what is this `type` thing in `type SomeType = { a: number, b: number }` ?

Comment: That defines a type (some kind of structure) in TypeScript (in this particular case, I could have also used `interface SomeType { ... }` instead)

Answer (score 1):

Try using webpack version `4.28.2` ` [here is the GitHub issue](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/6668)

Also change `export default SomeType` to `export { SomeType }`
and `import SomeType from './SomeType'` to `import { SomeType } from './SomeType'`

Comment: Thanks for the hint - unfortunately that did not work in my case :-(

Comment: @Natasha I don't think that you have changed the webpack of next.js check this https://github.com/zeit/next.js/pull/6702/commits/69cdcdf8b68847db053a0c27768b5b7c10e2d27b

Comment: @Natasha or go to `node_modules/next/package.json` you will find webpack there

Comment: @Natasha if you like you can post your github repo and I will make PR

Comment: Evgeni, that would be really great. The repo is here https://github.com/natasha-wse/nextjs-demo ... thank you very much ...

Comment: @Natasha sorry even after doing all that stuff and playing around or installing Next.js version 8.0.0-canary11 it still doesn't work which leave just one solution downgrading to version 7.0.2

Comment: Thanks Evgeni for all your help ... even with next@7.0.2 and webpack@4.20.2 I get the same error :-(

Comment: @Natasha I found the problem I will make a PR soon and I will update the answer

Comment: @Natasha I can't do a PR because there was to many changes here is my fork instead https://github.com/MarchWorks/nextjs-demo just clone it and then `npm run dev` don't do `npm install`

Comment: Thank you very much Evgeni for your support. Your fork is working properly. But hacking the packages in folder `node_modules` directly is not really an option (should never be an option, I think). Also, if I want to "default" export something, then I want to "default" export it and not go without default exports just because a build tool is buggy. No problem, I can wait until this is fixed in nextjs and webpack. Thank you very much that you've found out that this is a bug in the dependencies.